# Set default colours for lines just as default width \arrayrulewidth?

Tags: tables, color

In a table I want all the lines to be thick and in red color. I can change the width using `\arrayrulewidth`, but how to change the color to red?

Comment: Welcome to tex.stack....

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\arrayrulecolor` for that:

```
\documentclass[border=3.14]{standalone}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\arrayrulecolor{red}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[]{ll}
  \hline
  a & b \\
  \hline
  c & d \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]